# Javascript Event Listener Race Condition?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, race-condition, jquery-events, event-loop

I'm having a bit of an issue with a Javascript event listener. I'm trying to create an infinite scroll loader to show new data when the user scrolls down to the bottom of the page (like Instagram or Twitter). To accomplish this, I am using a solution I found on a different question using JQuery:

```js
function setWindowEventHandler(event, eventHandler) {
    if (event == "scroll") {
        $(window).on(event, async (e) => {
            console.log("Window Scroll Event");
            if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50) {
                // Remove event listener
                $(window).off(event);

                // Call event handler (await since it needs to fetch data)
                await eventHandler(e);

                // Add event listener again after event handler completed execution
                setWindowEventHandler("scroll", eventHandler);

            }
        });
    } else {
        // Add some other event to the window 
    }
}
```

The event handler function looks like this:

```js
let totalData = 20; // Arbitrary amount of total data that can be shown
let dataShown = 5; // Amount of data currently displayed to the user
let amountOfDataToGet = 5; // Get data in increments of 5 per query
handleWindowScroll = async (event) => {

    if (dataShown == totalData)
    {
        // Finished getting data
    } else {
        // Get more data (wait until promise has been received)
        let newData = await getData();

        // Show data to the user
        showData(newData);

        // Increase dataShown by amount queried
        dataShown += newData.length; 
    }

}
```

Now, this event fires multiple times when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page (within 50 pixels of the bottom). The problem is, that it seems that the event handler doesn't run synchronously - e.g., first event fires, scroll is within the 50 pixels at the bottom so it removes the event listener and calls the event handler. However, an arbitrary amount of events can fire and I suppose stop the execution of the previous event's event handler, so the dataShown global variable doesn't get updated, and what happens is that the event handler runs multiple times fetching the same data. My current solution is to treat it like a race condition, by adding a global variable that holds the amount of events that the event listener picked up:

```js
let amountOfWindowScrollEvents = 0;
function setWindowEventHandler(event, eventHandler) {
    if (event == "scroll") {
        $(window).on(event, async (e) => {
            console.log("Window Scroll Event");
            if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50) {
                // Immediately increase the amountOfWindowScrollEvents by 1
                amountOfWindowScrollEvents += 1;
                // Remove event listener
                $(window).off(event);

                // Call event handler only if there's only one event currently running (await since it needs to fetch data)
                if (amountOfWindowScrollEvents == 1) {
                    await eventHandler(e);

                    // Add event listener again after event handler completed execution
                    setWindowEventHandler("scroll", eventHandler);
                }
                // Decrease amountOfwindowScrollEvents by 1
                amountOfWindowScrollEvents -= 1;

            }
        });
    } else {
        // Add some over event to the window 
    }
}
```

This works, but I wonder if it's prone to a race condition - an event needs to increase the amountOfWindowScrollEvents by 1 and get to the if statement to run the event handler, but if it increases amountOfWindowScrollEvents by 1 then a second event also increases it by 1, its value is two and the event handler never gets called. That's certainly safer than the event handler getting fired multiple times, but I'm very confused as to why this is happening in the first place, especially since in my understanding Javascript is single-threaded and I would expect that if an event gets fired and an event listener catches it, it must be handled by the event handler to the end and only then a second event can get passed to the same event handler.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'd suggest working from a different example. *"it seems that the event handler doesn't run synchronously"* Indeed not, that's part of what the `async` means. The reason I wouldn't model your work on that answer is this code: `$(window).on(event, async (e) => { ... })`. That passes an `async` function into jQuery's `on`, which doesn't expect to receive an `async` function and won't do anything useful with the promise the function returns -- in particular, it won't handle errors. Nothing in the code does, either. :-|

Comment: Then how would you suggest to proceed? Should I use a vanilla DOM event handler for the scroll? The event handler needs to be async because it needs to query data. Could I remove the "async" in the `window.on()` event function if I change `await eventHandler(e)` to `eventHandler(e).then(() => {});`?

Comment: You could put `try`/`catch` around the body of the handler to handle errors. Then it would return a promise, but that  promise would never be rejected, which is fine since you know jQuery's event stuff will effectively ignore it if the handler returns a promise. My point was: The sample you're using didn't do that, which makes me distrust other code in it. :-)

Comment: I haven't personally written an infinite scroll yet (as a user, I hate it passionately, and fortunately no client has required that I do one for them yet). Handling overlapping calls to asynchronous processes is tedious, but possible. You shouldn't have to remove the handler and add it back, though; handle the overlap in the handler. *How* you do that will be fairly specific to your infinite scroll code.